# How to color individual text values in the combo box on selection?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm able to add background color to my `JComboBox` in Swing (Java). How to color individual text values in the combo box when user selects those?

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Comment: Don't rely just on color to signify selections.  Some people are color-blind.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) interface or extend [DefaultListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) to customize style of drop-down list items and set it:

```
jComboBox.setRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
```